# Rundeck 3.2.8 - Display all running executions

Tags: rundeck

we recently migrated to Rundeck 3.2.8 and before we used the 2.11.11. The problem is that we have more than 20 running executions per project but our Activity UI only show the 20 most recent without pagination. So it's now difficult for us to detect abnormal long running jobs. There is the paging returned by our "project/{project}/executions/running" endpoint :

```js
{
    "paging": {
        "count":20,
        "total":28,
        "offset":0,
        "max":20
    }
}
```

Is it normal to have by default a pagination for jobs already done but not for those which are in the course of execution? Is there a way to have this pagination? Because we had that pagination in 2.11.11.

Comment: Can you share any screenshot? Seems this known bug: https://github.com/rundeck/rundeck/pull/5469

Answer (score 0):

Add this line on your `rundeck-config.properties` file:

`rundeck.pagination.default.max=50`

And restart the Rundeck service. Now you can [see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2LhKh.jpg) all running jobs.

EDIT: this is an (ugly) workaround, that issue is reproduced [here](https://github.com/rundeck/rundeck/issues/6206) to follow up.